# jQuery Finding Position Of Element Relative to Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a little bit of a block in making my website, I need to spice it up a bit by adding animations but I can't seem to get this effect working: https://youtu.be/bToBgJYI8Pc. I am using a tutorial (https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/) because I don;t know jQuery as I did not think I would need it. My problem is that It seems that jQuery does not find the correct position of the elements I want to animate (They are repositioned with `position: relative;`)

Example 1. It's like the jQuery is running before the css and not taking any styles into account.

Example 2. It's like the anchors for the elements are a 4th of the page below where they are supposed to be (I don't even know if anchors even exist in css/html/jquery)

Example 3. Here is a GIF to show you what I mean. http://gyazo.com/fe72b683031e88d4247e62ae9e9fe5e8 Look at the text bodies under 'Screamer' 'Swezii' and 'KINZU'

Keep in mind I'm completely new to jQuery so you are going to need to explain in great detail to me what you are talking about if it has to do with jQuery.

Here is the Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  (function($) {

    /**
     * Copyright 2012, Digital Fusion
     * Licensed under the MIT license.
     * http://teamdf.com/jquery-plugins/license/
     *
     * @author Sam Sehnert
     * @desc A small plugin that checks whether elements are within
     *     the user visible viewport of a web browser.
     *     only accounts for vertical position, not horizontal.
     */

    $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

      var $t = $(this),
        $w = $(window),
        viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
        viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
        _top = $t.offset().top,
        _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
        compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
        compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

      return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

    };

  })(jQuery);

  var win = $(window);

  var allMods = $(".animated");

  allMods.each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      el.addClass("already-visible");
    }
  });

  win.scroll(function(event) {

    allMods.each(function(i, el) {
      var el = $(el);
      if (el.visible(true)) {
        el.addClass("come-in");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
/* Managers */

/* 278 PX */

#managersbg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 495px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 288px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 495px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 295px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 455px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 358px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 364px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 416px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 485px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 624px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 450px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 671px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 914px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500
}
#managers {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
#screamer,
#swezii,
#kinzu {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#screamer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#swezii {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
}
#kinzu {
  position: relative;
  top: 275px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  position: relative;
}
#manager1 {
  top: -115px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  font-weight: 600
}
#manager2 {
  top: 45px;
}
#manager3 {
  top: 195px;
}
#text1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -165px;
}
#text2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #text1,
  #text2,
  #text3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
    text-align: center;
  }
}
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TheVersionArts Studio</title>
  <meta name="description" content="TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We provide clients with quality design at a small cost.">
  <meta name="author" content="TheVersionArts">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- CSS
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">

  <!-- Favicon
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

  <!-- Scripts
 -------------------------------------------------- -->
  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/animated.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
 –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <img src="images/bg.png" id="background">

  <div id="headerbg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="five columns">
          <img src="images/thv-header.png" id="header">
        </div>
        <div class="seven columns">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutbg">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h4 id="about">About Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <p>TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We were founded in the winter of 2014. We connect clients to the designers they need. Our goal is to serve high quality design at an affordable price through the internet. We strive to impress our
              clients. We don't sell graphics, or designs. We sell art and colours.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns" id="aboutbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="managersbg">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <h4 id="managers">Our Managers</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column" id="screamer">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column" id="swezii">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column" id="kinzu">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager1">Screamer</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager2">Swezii</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <p id="manager3">KINZU</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text1">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text2">I love the fliudity of art, of any kind!. It is my goal to become a bettter designer myself so I can share my knowldge with others. I am one of the best designers for my price.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">
            <p id="text3">I'm that guy chilling on his computer, creating fantastic art for you. You can bet you'll get what you ask for!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out your positioning code, that seems to be the main problem.
Here is the css (I added the come-in class to get it working in the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kaemgm6y/

I din't alter the javascript at all. Here is the css file I used.

Also I added borders for visual/debugging effect - you can remove those later.

```
 /* Managers */

/* 278 PX */

#managersbg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0.79);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 495px;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 288px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 495px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 295px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 350px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 455px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 358px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 364px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 416px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 485px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 510px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 540px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 470px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 624px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 450px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 460px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 671px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 435px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 775px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 410px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 420px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 914px) {
  #managersbg {
    top: 400px;
  }
}
h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500
}
h2{
    text-align:center;
}
div.animated{
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
#managers {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
#screamer,
#swezii,
#kinzu {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: rgba(255, 153, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*#screamer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#swezii {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
}
#kinzu {
  position: relative;
  top: 275px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  position: relative;
}*/
/*#manager1 {
  top: -115px;
}
#manager1,
#manager2,
#manager3 {
  font-weight: 600
}
#manager2 {
  top: 45px;
}
#manager3 {
  top: 195px;
}*/
/*#text1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -165px;
}
#text2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}*/
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  #text1,
  #text2,
  #text3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    /*transform: translateX(-25%);*/
    text-align: center;
  }
}
p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.come-in {
  transform: translateY(150px);
  animation: come-in 0.8s ease forwards;
}
.come-in:nth-child(odd) {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}
.already-visible {
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes come-in {
  to { transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

Also I changed the HTML.  I combined some of the divs.  They can have multiple classes in the same div like so:

```
<div class="animated one-third-column" id="kinzu">

</div>
```

The other thing that helped was putting the headers (manager names and the paragraph in the same div - this makes it almost impossible to get them wrongly positioned on top of each other.

Here is my altered HTML (needs more cleanup, but you get the idea):

```
<body>

  <!-- Primary Page Layout
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <img src="images/bg.png" id="background">

  <div id="headerbg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="five columns">
          <img src="images/thv-header.png" id="header">
        </div>
        <div class="seven columns">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#designers">Designers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="aboutbg">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
          <h4 id="about">About Us</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <p>TheVersionArts is a private design studio. We were founded in the winter of 2014. We connect clients to the designers they need. Our goal is to serve high quality design at an affordable price through the internet. We strive to impress our
              clients. We don't sell graphics, or designs. We sell art and colours.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns" id="aboutbar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="managersbg">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <h4 id="managers">Our Managers</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated one-third-column" id="screamer">

        </div>
        <div class="animated one-third-column" id="swezii">

        </div>
        <div class="animated one-third-column" id="kinzu">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <h2 id="manager1">Screamer</h2>
              <p id="text1">I am a guy who loves to get the things in my head onto paper. I have some great ideas that will blow your minds! Get ready!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <h2 id="manager2">Swezii</h2>
              <p id="text2">I love the fliudity of art, of any kind!. It is my goal to become a bettter designer myself so I can share my knowldge with others. I am one of the best designers for my price.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="one-third-column">
            <h2 id="manager3">KINZU</h2>
              <p id="text3">I'm that guy chilling on his computer, creating fantastic art for you. You can bet you'll get what you ask for!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="seven columns">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
```